# How to find all the related Child Objects metadata - standard and custom

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, standard-objects

How to find all the related Child Objects metadata - standard and custom except system objects like AttachedDocumentLink, ProcessInstance etc.

Below is my requirement

1. On a custom VF page, user enters a record Id in an input field and presses submit
2. Use that record Id to find the source Object
3. Then use metadata to find all the related Child Objects - standard and custom
4. Query the standard and custom objects to retrieve the records (Id, Name, and all system fields are fine)

In step 3, I'm getting all the system related objects which I don't want.
Below is my code

```
public with sharing class ViewObjectRecordController
{
    public Id recordId{get;set;}
    public String recordName{get;set;}

    public List<sObject> getObjectAndChildRecordsList()
    {
        List<sObject> recordList = new List<sObject>();
        Set<String> objectAPIs = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, String> childToParentFieldApi = new Map<String, String>();
        try
        {
            if(recordId != null)
            {
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult SObjectResult = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
                for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: SObjectResult.getChildRelationships())
                {
                    if(cr.getRelationshipName() != null)
                    {
                    objectAPIs.add(cr.getRelationshipName()+'');
                    }
                }

                String soql = 'SELECT Id,  Name, CreatedById, LastModifiedById, OwnerId FROM '+SObjectResult.getName()+' WHERE ID = \''+recordId+'\'';
                recordList = Database.query(soql);
                soql = 'SELECT Id ';
                if(objectAPIs.size() > 0 && objectAPIs.size() < 100)
                {
                    soql = soql + ',';
                    Integer i = 1;
                    for(String api: objectAPIs)
                    {
                        soql = soql + '(select Id,Name, CreatedById, LastModifiedById, OwnerId FROM '+api+') ';
                        if(i != objectAPIs.size())
                        {
                            soql = soql + ',';
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                soql = soql + 'FROM '+SObjectResult.getName()+' WHERE ID = \''+recordId+'\'';
                for(sObject objRecord: Database.query(soql))
                {
                    for(String api: objectAPIs)
                    {
                        if(objRecord.getSObjects('\''+api+'\'').size() > 0)
                        {
                            for(sObject childRecord : objRecord.getSObjects('\''+api+'\''))
                            {
                                recordList.add(childRecord);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.debug('Total records = '+recordList.size());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return ApexPages.hasMessages() ? null : recordList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more detail about your objective and what you have tried so far. See [ask].

Comment: @David Reed I have modified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Object names . If it's a custom one and it has relation with that given object then the API name must contain **__r**.
From this, you can easily find out which one is a standard one and which one is custom.

Comment: Thanks Arabinda. But I have to avoid the system objects like Attachments, Histories, feeds etc., Need to consider only standard salesforce objects

Comment: You can create custom metadata to store all required standard object names. In your logic read that custom metadata and parse the value and prepare a list. Then check if the list contains the API name, go for standard object processing else if it contains __r go for custom object process.

Comment: Thanks Arabinda that works for me :)